# How to use background image in external css using react js?

Tags: css, reactjs, css-selectors, external

folder structure of image:

[image]

unable to use background image using external css in reactjs

Comment: in react.js you need to `import` image as a module or use `required`,  wrap your relative path with `required`,

`background-image: url(required('./images/1.jpg'))`

also in react.js, all the folders must be in `src` directory and in react components you cant access the out of the `src` directory